# Why is the ViewBag data empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, itext

I'm trying to create a pdf from my webpage by using MVC and iText, but when I reach the View the `ViewBag` data is empty.

In the Controller the ViewBag still had values.

Why is the ViewBag data empty?

Starts in the View:

```
<td><span>
    <a href='<%: Url.Action("HitlijstNaarPdf", new { AID_Hitlijst = ViewBag.Huidig })%>' target="_blank">
        Download lijst
    </a></span>
</td>
```

Call the Result in the Controller

```
public FileStreamResult HitlijstNaarPdf(int? AID_Hitlijst = 0)
{
    SelectPeriode(AID_Hitlijst);
    GetHitlijstSettings();
    var model = new HitlijstModel();
    string sHtmlInhoud= this.RenderView("Index", model);

    FileStreamResult result = PDFGenerator(sHtmlInhoud);
    return result;
}

private void GetHitlijstSettings()
{
    ViewBag.Datum = FHitlijstSettings.Datum;
    ViewBag.Jaar = FHitlijstSettings.Jaar;
    ViewBag.Week = FHitlijstSettings.Week;
}
```

In the class ControllerExtensions:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string RenderView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        return RenderView(controller, viewName, new ViewDataDictionary(model));
    }

    public static string RenderView(this Controller controller, string viewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    {
        var controllerContext = controller.ControllerContext;

        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null);

        StringWriter stringWriter;

        using (stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewData,
                controllerContext.Controller.TempData,
                stringWriter);

            // Here viewResult.ViewBag.Week still has data
            // by debugging you see:
            // viewResult.ViewBag.Week = 14;
            // viewResult.ViewBag.Datum = "maandag 6 april 1987";
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
        }

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

And when the system returns to the View (ViewBag.Week <=> null):

```
<th class="hitlijst_datum">Hitlijst&nbsp;-&nbsp;nummer&nbsp;<%: ViewBag.Week %>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%: ViewBag.Datum  %></th>
```

You get the following message:

**The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(string, params object[])' and 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char[])'**

I have tried: Html.Raw and ToString => **Html.Raw**(ViewBag.Week.**ToString()**) too,  but that doesn't work either. What do I have to do to ensure the ViewBag is not empty in the View?

Comment: How is this related to iText? I don't see any iText code anywhere!

Comment: I've added the code related to iText.

Comment: Duh! `HtmlWorker`? That class has been abandoned a long time because (1.) it was an ad hoc implementation of only a limited set of HTML tags, and (2.) the code was beyond repair. You should use iTextSharp's [XML Worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlworker) instead.

Comment: But the ViewBag is still empty.

Comment: Well, I'm the original developer of iText and I have never heard of something called a `ViewBag`, hence I repeat my initial question: *How is this related to iText?* Why on earth did you add that tag?

Comment: string sHtmlInhoud= this.RenderView("Index", model); ... and then: <th class="hitlijst_datum">Hitlijst&nbsp;-&nbsp;nummer&nbsp;<%: ViewBag.Week %>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%: ViewBag.Datum  %></th>. It's before iText. I have to get the html-contents for creating the pdf.

Comment: I don't see any code where you are actually placing values in the ViewBag (which is part of Asp.Net, not itext)

Comment: The placing values was not important, because in the method RenderView the values were still available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String. I replace ControllerExtensions with this source. And it works. If someone can tell me, why the ViewBag via the ControllerExtensions class disappeared. Nice to hear.